# Laravel DB::unprepared

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-4.2

Just the 1st and 2nd statment works. When it comes to the third and fourth one, no results can be seen on the database.
I checked the logs (centos x64) for both php and mariadb but no errors recorded. No exceptions thrown too in try/catch blocks.

```
DB::unprepared('    

CREATE TABLE clone1 LIKE table1;
INSERT clone1 SELECT * FROM table1
WHERE field LIKE "'.$value.'%";

CREATE TABLE clone2 LIKE table2;
INSERT clone2 SELECT * FROM table2;
WHERE field LIKE "'.$value.'%";

CREATE TABLE clone3 LIKE table3;
INSERT clone3 SELECT * FROM table3;
WHERE field LIKE "'.$value.'%";

CREATE TABLE clone4 LIKE table4;
INSERT clone4 SELECT * FROM table4;
WHERE field LIKE "'.$value.'%";

');
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Easy answer:** I removed the commas from the end of the insert rows, which was caused the query to stop before where statements.